# Bulk writes when one object requires the Key of another

Tags: google-cloud-datastore, app-engine-ndb

Trying to figure out a good solution to this. Using Python and the NDB library.

I want to create an entity, and that entity is also tied to another entity. Both are created at the same time. Example would be creating a Message for a large number of users. We have an `Inbox` table/kind, and a `Message` table.

So once we gather the Keys of all the users we want, what I'm doing is just creating the `Inbox` entity, saving it, and then using the provided Key that it returns and attaching to the `Message`, and then saving the `Message`. For a large number of users, this seems pretty expensive. 2 writes per user. Normally I would just create the objects themselves and then use `ndb.put_multi()` to just batch the writes. Since there is no `Key` until it's saved, I can't do that.

Hope that made sense. Ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the allocate_ids API. You can pass a parent key and get id assigned. The allocate_ids call guarantees that the id is never reused within that parent key context. allocate_ids is a small operation and fast. Once you allocate these ids, then you can do the put_multi by referencing the allocated ids in the other entities that refer them. As I understand the message entity itself is not being referenced and if so you only need to allocate ids for Inbox (presumably if the user already doesn't have one) and do a multi_put on both inbox and message entities.

Comment: This seems exactly what I'm looking for. I figure I make the `allocate_ids()` call within the `for` loop? Does mean potentially thousands of those calls. Or should I pre-allocate using the `size` argument, since I know how many keys I'll need? and just grab the index of which, using the same index identifier as my `for` loop?

Comment: At a time you can allocate 500 ids. See https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/concepts/limits